# How do i run a code after forloop has stopped?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

Hi is it possible to show a messagebox after 3 failed attempts for the pin to appear. Currently what i want my codes to do is, after 3 failed attempts, it will update a new random pin in the database. So when it has been updated, i want to show a messagebox that shows that a new pin has been sent. So this is my current code.

```
    string[] pinArray = new string[3];
    private void PinError()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < pinArray.Length; i++)
        {


            if (pinArray[i] != null)
            {

                string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PostParcel set Pin=@pin1 where Box='1'and Pin!= '' ", myConnect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin1", RandomNumber(1000, 9999));
                myConnect.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnect.Close();
            }
            else if (pinArray[i] == null)
            {
                pinArray[i] = txtpBox1.Text;

                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. Pin Will Change After " + (3 - i) + " More Attempts");

                break;

            }

        }
    }
```

I have tried placing

```
MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. New Pin Has Been Sent.");
break;
```

in the 'if{}' section at the end. But trying the second failed attempt, it will show the messagebox "Invalid Pin. New Pin Has Been Sent.". Which made me realised that, on the second attempt, the 'if' will run. So technically, the pin would have been changed at the second attempt already. Is it possible to not let it change at the second attempt until the 3rd attempt and also to show a messagebox when the pin has been updated?

I have also tried adding

```
if (i == 2) continue;
```

into

```
if (pinArray[i] != null){  **if (i == 2) continue;** }
```

but on the second attempt it will just  show that a new pin has been sent

P.s, sorry if this sorta question has been answered before. And thanks in advance for helping.

i kinda just did this

```
            if (pinArray[i] != null)
            {
                if (i == 2) continue;
                string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PostParcel set Pin=@pin1 where Box='1'and Pin!= '' ", myConnect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin1", RandomNumber(1000, 9999));
                myConnect.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. New Pin Has Been Sent");
                break;

            }
```

Comment: do you have the condition like `if(i == 2){/*show message*/}`? Can you show full code how you are calling `"Invalid Pin. New Pin Has Been Sent."` message?

Comment: @Bharadwaj i added the part into the question part cause it was too long to be a comment

Comment: if I am correct `PinError()` is called once every wrong pin is entered for 3 times? and are you working on web application or window application?

Comment: Your code is correct, you don't need `if (i == 2) continue;` condition. It is executing at `i == 2`, but it doesn't mean that it is second attempt. Since you are using `i` for looping by setting it to `0` initially. So `i == 2` will be third attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `PinError()` for every wrong pin entered, try this below code

```
int i = 1;

private void PinError()
{
     if(i != 3)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. Pin Will Change After " + (3 - i) + " More Attempts");
         i++;
         return;
     }

     string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PostParcel set Pin=@pin1 where Box='1'and Pin!= '' ", myConnect);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin1", RandomNumber(1000, 9999));
     myConnect.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     myConnect.Close();
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. New Pin Has Been Sent");
}
```

Comment: omg this works perfectly. thanks. and so not complicated. hahah i dont know why i was using an array. totally forgot about count. anyways i added `if (i == 3){i = 1;}` at the back to make it re count when all attempts has been used. thankssssss

Answer (score 2):

Set a `bool` when the pin is assigned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pinArray.Length; i++)
{


    if (pinArray[i] != null)
    {

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PostParcel set Pin=@pin1 where Box='1'and Pin!= '' ", myConnect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin1", RandomNumber(1000, 9999));
        myConnect.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnect.Close();

        assigned = true;
    }
}

if (!assigned)
{
    pinArray[i] = txtpBox1.Text;

    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. A new one will be assigned");

    break;

}
```

Comment: hey anyways. i'm gna use the count thing. cause i am not so familiar with bool hahah but thanksss

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional condidition to your elseif expression to check the index of loop. It its less than 2 (since you start index is 0, and you have 3 loop) you don't show the pop up. Like the following:

```
else if (pinArray[i] == null && **i > 2**)
        {
            pinArray[i] = txtpBox1.Text;

            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin. Pin Will Change After " + (3 - i) + " More Attempts");

            break;

        }
```